# xshift-ing a scope inside a tikzpicture doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following LaTeX code saved in the file `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

Hello, world!

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[xshift=1]
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code is meant to create the following output:

[image: Expected output: lower square is shifted]

However, once compiled with `pdflatex test` the actual output is:

[image: Actual output: both squares start at the same x-position]

Why isn't the lower square shifted 1 cm to the right relative to the upper square? Is there a way to affect such a shift from within the `tikzpicture` environment without changing the code for drawing the rectangle?

Comment: `xshift=1` means `xshift=1pt`. Did you mean `xshift=1cm` or `shift={(1,0)}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke: `xshift=1cm` produces the same output as `xshift=1`.

Comment: Ah, now I see what's wrong. The scopes are not in the same picture. All coordinates and offsets in a tikzpicture are relative to the drawing and not absolute to the page. While you can mess with the bounding box in weird ways I would suggest that you just add `\hspace{1cm}` before `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. the default measurement unit when Ti*k*Z expects a length is `pt`, so your `1` means `1pt`, not `1cm` as it seems you expect.
2. Even then, if you shift your internal coordinates by 1cm, but you have a figure that is contained between the coordinates (1,0) and (2,1), the bounding box of the figure is still a square of 1cm x 1cm... and it's positioned as a character, so there is no difference in the final output.

   If you want to have a shifted picture with a bigger bounding box, you need to *put something* in (0,0):

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

Hello, world!

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

Hello, world!

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you add a `fbox{}` around each picture, you can see the effect:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The coordinate system of `tikzpicture` is not respect to your document page, so as the second `tikzpicture` has only one element (your new rectangle) it hasn't a point of comparison to look shifted 1 unity to the right. It has been moved but you can't see it until you put another elements to have some "perspective" in the same image.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
%Hello, world!

%\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
%\end{tikzpicture}

%Hello, world!

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) at (0,0) {Hello, world!};
\draw (A.west) ++ (0.15,-0.2) rectangle ++ (1,-1);

\node (B) at (0, -1.2-0.4) {Hello, world!};
\draw (B.east) ++ (-0.15,-0.2) rectangle ++ (-1,-1);

% Or using scope:
%\begin{scope}[yshift=-28mm, xshift=-1mm]
%   \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
%\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]